# Switch on Any.Type

Tags: swift

I'm trying to switch on a type in swift. I'm not trying to switch on the type of an object instance, I'm trying to switch on the actual type itself. For example:

```
 let t: Any.Type = Int.self
 switch t {
 case is Int:
     print("int")
 default:
     print("other")
 }
```

I would expect this to print "int" but it falls into the default case.

I can accomplish the desired result with an if statement, as in,

```
 if t == Int.self
 {
     print("t is an int")
 }
```

but I was hoping for a way to do this with a switch. I've read Apple's 'Type Casting' documentation, perhaps not thoroughly enough because I can't see a way to apply it here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Xcode generates the following warning on the above case: "Cast from 'Any.Type' to unrelated Type 'Int' always fails" which hints at the correct way:

```
 let t: Any.Type = Int.self
 switch t {
 case is Int.Type:
     print("Int")
 default:
     print("Other")
 }
```